# PHP $_SESSION Implementation

Tags: php, authentication, session-variables

Does anyone know how PHP maps session IDs to $_SESSION arrays?  In other words, given session ID x, where does PHP pull the values from to populate the $_SESSION array?

And given a session ID and the url it came from, is there any possibility of someone being able to gain access to the values in the $_SESSION array?

Comment: PHP fills this array from a file named after ID. given a session ID, someone will gain access to the session. that's exact purpose of session ID. However, access to array does  have PHP script only

Comment: Yes, I understand that the purpose of the session ID is for server-side scripts to access the values in the $_SESSION array.  What I'm asking is if the session ID allows non-local users to access those values as well.

Comment: @Shrapnel: But only if PHPSESSID is enabled.

Comment: @Dufel: If PHPSESSID is enabled, anyone can append `?PHPSESSID=a-session-id` to an URL, and gain access to that session.

Comment: @Znarkus what nonsense you are trying to say? What do you mean "PHPSESSID is enabled"?

Comment: Sam, can you please be more precise in your fears? What exactly do you mean - a variable? A file contents?

Comment: It's alright, I've already learned what I was looking for from the other answers.  Was just curious about how secure the contents of the $_SESSION array are.  I realize that it's possible to steal someone else's session - what I wanted to know was if there's any way for a remote user to directly access the session values.

Comment: @Znarkus: `session.use_only_cookies` controls the behavior you're referring to, and defaults to 1 in newer releases (therefore ignoring session IDs passed in via query string).

Comment: A remote user doesn't have access to PHP variables. Only running code does have access to it's variables. Variable is a subject of program. It exists only when program being run. And exists only within this running program. No other program can access a variable.

Comment: @R. Bemrose Thanks, I've got that Znarkus mean. However, it doesn't matter anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, PHP uses the `files` [session handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-handler).  These files are stored based on the `session.save_path` setting, but defaults to the system's temp directory (a highly insecure location, consider changing it)

This session handler stores each session as a serialized PHP array in a file named with the session ID.

If you can find out a session ID prior to it being cleaned up by the session garbage collection routine, it can be hijacked, as PHP does not internally do any sanity checks.  You may wish to do your own by storing the user's IP address in the session and comparing it to their current IP, clearing the session if they don't match.

`session.gc_maxlifetime` controls how many seconds a session will be considered valid.  After this point, the session has a small chance of being deleted every time a request occurs.  Default is 1440 seconds (or 24 minutes).

By default, this chance is 1%, but can be altered by adjusting the `session.gc_probability` and `session.gc_divisor` values (they default to 1 and 100 respectively).

There are other session handlers as well, such as the ones included with the [memcache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) or [memcached](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) extensions.  There was once one based on the `libmm` shared memory library, but I believe that has been discontinued.

Comment: On the subject of session sanity checks, I spoke too soon. PHP has one session sanity check it can do, but it's based on the HTTP_REFERER value, which is controlled by the user and easily spoofable.

Answer (score 2):

Session info is stored on server filesystem. There's configuration parameter session.save_path in php.ini. Some info about sessions security is given here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.security.php

Answer (score 2):

Session data is usually stored in temporary files on disk (see the [session.save_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) setting) and the filename reflects the session ID.

In general, yes, if someone gets hold of another user's session ID and sends it along with his own request, he will gain access to that user's session. One way of solving this is to bind sessions to IP addresses and invalidate the session when a request arrives from a different address.

Comment: The default for `session.use_only_cookies` was changed at some point to default to on, for the good of everyone involved! ;)  I don't know what version changed that, though.  Having said that, the cookie still contains a session ID.

Comment: @R. Bemrose: Ahh thank you. I somehow misinterpreted that parameter as meaning to store *data* in cookies.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no possibility!

...unless your code or the code of any component used is insecure.

Answer (score 1):

With the default implementation of sessions (which can be replaced by a custom one if needed) the data is stored in local files. Your server receives the session ID from the client in a cookie, finds the corresponding local file on your server and populates data into $_SESSION.

Gaining access to this data requires file-level access on the server, which is not impossible, unless your server is *secure enough*.

Answer (score 0):

You can also [write your own](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/10/3/7) session handler to save the session to a database.

Also, if you want to make it harder to pin down the session ID, [regenerate the session ID](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) at strategic times (on privilege elevation, etc) -- or as often as you want.

Pass `session_regenerate_id()` the argument `True` to destroy the old session data.